GDAL get vsimem file byte array while using Java binding
i have saved a dataset to PNG file.
file = "/vsimem/output.png"; out_drv.CreateCopy(file, dstile, 0, new String[0]); 
then I want to get the file's byte array and save the bytes to a database.
In C++ GDAL，VSIGetMemFileBuffer can convert /vsimem/** file to byte[], but I can not find corresponding method in Java GDAL. What can I do to use it in Java?
Version info:
GDAL 3.6.3
